# How to get refreshed data from database using spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to `Spring Framework`.
I am using `Spring framework` to access `database` like `oracle`.
All the `DML` operations are working fine.And i am using `RowMapper` to access data form a database table and it shows the `record` correctly.But the problem is that if suppose i directly delete a record from database table using `delete` command in oracle and inserts some another record then in my application i.e. the `java application` it is not showing the refreshed data from `database table` and it only shows the deleted records not the refreshed data.Please give me some valuable suggestions...Thank You.

Here is my `code` to access table and set data:

```
public List<StudentPojo> getAllStudents(){
        String query = "select * from demo";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<StudentPojo>(){
        @Override
        public StudentPojo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {
            StudentPojo stud = new StudentPojo();
                stud.setName(rs.getString(1));
                stud.setMail(rs.getString(2));
                stud.setPhone(rs.getString(3));
                stud.setSex(rs.getString(4));
                return stud;
            }
        });
    }
```

And The `code` to show data :

```
List<StudentPojo> list = data.getAllStudents();
                if(!list.isEmpty()){
                    for(StudentPojo student : list){
                        System.out.println(student.getName() + " | " + student.getMail() + " | " + student.getPhone() + " | " + student.getSex() );
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("No Record Found");
                }
```

Comment: Did you commit your changes to database, after delete and insert statement?

Comment: Thanks  @Alexander ....Actually i didn't commit....Now it resolved my issue...